# Having a challenge converting data into the appropriate format. ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1000) vs (None, 1))

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Iam getting this error when I'm fitting a model: ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1000) vs (None, 1)). I am not sure how to fix it.
Below is the code producing it.

```
Directory = 'dataset'
Classes = ['with_mask', 'without_mask']

train_data =[]
def make_training_data():
    for category in Classes:
        path = os.path.join(Directory, category)
        class_nums = Classes.index(category) #transforms with_mask and without_mask into 1 and 0
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_path = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))
                res_img = cv2.resize(img_path, (224, 224))
                train_data.append([res_img, class_nums])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            
#shuffle data
import random
random.shuffle(train_data)

#create dependent and independent variables
x= [] #data
y = [] #labels

for features, labels in train_data:
    x.append(features)
    y.append(labels)
    
#reshaping data into numpy arrays that the models understand    
x=np.array(x).reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)
Y = np.array(y)

#normalizing the data
X =x/255.0

model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet()

base_input = model.layers[0].input
base_output = model.layers[-4].output
#adding other layers
flat_layer = layers.Flatten()(base_output)
final_output =layers.Dense(1)(flat_layer) #output is either 1 or 0
final_output= layers.Activation('sigmoid')(final_output)

new_model = keras.Model(inputs =base_input, outputs = final_output)
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error trace?

Comment: I'm editing my question to add it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this for your model

```
base_model= tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet( include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3), pooling='max', weights='imagenet',dropout=.4) 
x=base_model.output
final_output=layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
new_model = keras.Model(inputs =base_model.input, outputs = final_output)
new_model.compile(Adam(lr=.001), loss='tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```